# Rendering list items using map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've the following array,

```
var IMAGES = [
    {
      src: 'http://placehold.it/325x250',
      mediaId: 'something'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://placehold.it/325x250',
      mediaId: 'something'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://placehold.it/325x250',
      mediaId: 'something'
    }
]
```

This is my React component where I wish to render the array.

```
function Viewer(props){
  return (
    <div className= 'row'>
      <div className= 'image-viewer'>
        <ul className='list-inline'>
        {props.images.map(function(image){
          <li><a href='#'><img src= {image.src} className='img-responsive img-rounded img-thumbnail' alt= {image.mediaId}/></a></li>
        })}

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how I'm declaring the props.

```
    Viewer.propTypes = {
      images: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
        src : React.PropTypes.string,
        mediaId: React.PropTypes.string
      }))
    };
```

This is how I'm passing the props inside the main container.

```
function App(props){
  return (
    <div className= 'container-fluid'>
      <Header />
      <div>

      </div>
      <Viewer images={IMAGES}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The list doesn't get rendered, and I don't get any array.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement in your mapping function:

```
{props.images.map(function(image){
    return <li><a href='#'><img src= {image.src} className='img-responsive img-rounded img-thumbnail' alt= {image.mediaId}/></a></li>
})}
```

Comment: Thanks, this renders the component, but I get the following error in the console. `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: Have a look at [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: yes, you should add `<li key={src}` assuming src is unique.  if not, you can add `i' as the second argument of the callback and use it as a key.

Comment: Actually got it. Thanks.